# Process memory usage is rising to 1.8GB - Is there a more efficient way to write?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I am reading the content of a file and writing it to a SharePoint external List(SQL). There is around 35000 lines in the file. I am receiving the error below in SharePoint and process memory usage is rising to 1.8GB (This is when error occurs) around 10000 records make it- Is there a more efficient way to write on the client side to use less memory or is there a limit to the amount of data that can be sent to an external SharePoint list at once?

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee4, Could not complete
>   the operation due to error 00002ee4

```
function readFile() {     
    /*Access Sharepoint Web*/
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var fileUrl;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(oWebsite);
    /*Loads the content of specified text file*/
    //we will declare the text file name to be the most recent added by   

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        fileUrl = oWebsite.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/MytextFile.txt";
        $.ajax({
            url: fileUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
        })
        .done(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandlerrf))
        .error(Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandlerrf));
    }, errorHandler);

    function successHandlerrf(data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        var lineItems = lines.length;
        var lines1 =[];

        for(i;i<=x ;i++){
            lines1 = lines[i].substring(0,14); 
            oListItem.set_item('Document_Number', lines1).trim();
            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(oListItem);

            // break;
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync( );
   }
   $('#loading').html('');
   alert("Complete");
}
```

Comment: try it with a non-microsoft browser..

Comment: your missing a `}` to close your `for` loop. Also you dont seem to have defined `i` in your `for` loop, or `x` for that matter, so how is it supposed to loop?

Comment: I tried Firefox and same issue.